# Differences in LINQ vs Method expression

Tags: c#, linq

Why the Linq expression IL results in omission of the Select projection whereas the corresponding method expression keeps the Select projection ?

I suppose these two pieces of code does the same.

```
 var a = from c in companies
                where c.Length >10
                select c;

//

var b = companies.Where(c => c.Length > 10).Select(c => c);

//IL - LINQ

IEnumerable<string> a = this.companies.
Where<string>(CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1);

//IL

   IEnumerable<string> b = this.companies.Where<string>
   (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate4).Select<string, string>
   (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate5);
```

Then why the difference in IL?

**EDITED** : 
 then why

```
  var a = from c in companies
           select c;
```

result in SELECT projection even inside IL. it can also be omitted right ?

Comment: .Select(c => c) is completely redundant and so is the resulting IL

Comment: @Adam ..Please see my updated Question.That should also be reduntant right ?

Comment: No, that not redundant. If you would omit the Select call in your edited example, the query would just return the original collection, whereas Select returns an IEnumerable. In your first example, Where already returns an IEnumerable and the select clause doesn't do any work, so it is omitted.

Comment: @Maximillain .. Thanks..That makes sense.i could accept that as an answer.

Comment: I'll convert it to an answer then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example, the call to Select is not redundant. If you would omit the Select call, the query would just return the original collection, whereas Select returns an IEnumerable.

In your first example, Where already returns an IEnumerable and the select clause doesn't do any work, so it is omitted.

Comment: Are you assuming that 'companies' is not already an IEnumerable? If so, this makes sense. If the collection already was an enumerable, calling Select will still not make any sense.

Comment: It WILL make sense. Take the following code: var a = from c in companies select c; Now, let companies be a List of CompanyData. Now, if Select isn't omitted, what is the type of a? It's a List of CompanyData! And if it isn't omitted? Than a is an IEnumerable of CompanyData.

Comment: What type 'a' ends up with is secondary, it will still support IEnumerable. Calling Select only to do a cast seems like a huge waste of cycles.

Comment: ...oh well, in light of @Ani's answer about degenerate query expressions, you're right, it DOES make sense :)

Comment: @PeterLillevold, if you return a `List<T>` then you can modify the original collection, which could have any number of consequences.  This is not the cast with an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @smartcaveman - if we're talking about what type a method returns, I agree. This is not the case here, though. Within the scope of a method call, whether a variable is explicitly typed `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>` is not a huge concern. When defining the return types of methods in an API, I would think twice about what type to return.

Comment: @PeterLillevold, I was not talking about the return type of the method, but the actual reference that is returned.  You wrote "Calling Select only to do a cast"...  But, that is not what is happening.  You are returning a `WhereSelectListIterator\`2` instead of the list, which cannot be modified.  Otherwise, you could abuse the API by casting the returned `IEnumerable\`1` implementation back to the `List\`1`,  - Basically, the select does more than just the cast the List as your comment seemed to indicate (though perhaps I misunderstood what you meant?)

Comment: @smartcaveman - ah yes, I agree. That's why I replied earlier in this thread that calling `Select` does make sense, in that the effect of passing the elements unfiltered and untransformed through a new iterator hides the original source.

Answer (score 5):

The C# compiler is clever and remove useless statement from Linq. Select c is useless so the compiler remove it. When you write Select(c=>c) the compiler can't say that's the instruction is useless because it' a function call and so it doesn't remove it.
If you remove it yourself IL become the same.

EDIT :
Linq is a "descriptive" language : you say what you want and the compiler transforms it well. You don't have any control on that transformation. The compiler try to optimize function call and don't use Select because you don't do projection so it's useless.
When you write Select(c => c) you call a function explicitely so the compiler won't remove it.

```
var a = from c in companies select c;
var a = c.Select(elt=>elt);
```

Select is usefull in this example. If you remove it a has the type of c; otherwise a is an IEnumerable

Comment: I know .my question is  why it automatically removed only on LINQ and not on Method query expression?

Comment: but if you write `var a = from c in companies select c;` compiler wont remove it

Comment: The LINQ syntax is translated to method calls by the compiler. It will translate your LINQ syntax to companies.Where(c => c.Length > 10).  You have added .Select(c => c) to your equivalent for no reason.

Answer (score 5):

@mexianto is of course correct that this is a compiler optimization.

Note that this is explicitly called out in the language specification under "Degenerate Query expressions." Also note that the compiler is smart enough to *not* perform the optimization when doing so would return the original source object (the user might want to use a degenerate query to make it difficult for the client to mutate the source object, assuming that it is mutable).

> **7.16.2.3 Degenerate query expressions**
>
> A query expression of the form

```
from x in e select x
```

> is translated into

```
( e ) . Select ( x => x )
```

> [...] A degenerate query expression is one that
>   trivially selects the elements of the source. A later phase of the
>   translation removes degenerate queries introduced by other translation
>   steps by replacing them with their source. It is important however to
>   ensure that the result of a query expression is never the source
>   object itself, as that would reveal the type and identity of the
>   source to the client of the query. Therefore this step protects
>   degenerate queries written directly in source code by explicitly
>   calling Select on the source. It is then up to the implementers of
>   Select and other query operators to ensure that these methods never
>   return the source object itself.

Comment: That was a wonderful explanation.......+1.Could have accepted this as an answer but for Maximillain 's who has come with the explanation first..

Answer (score 1):

Because in the query version there is no actual select projecting 'c' into something else, it is just passing on 'c' as-is. Which results in only a call to 'Where'.

In the second variation, you explicitly call 'Select' and thus do a projection. Yes, you are only returning the same objects, but the compiler will not see this.